# supermicro server - long time for reboot

Tags: memory, boot, supermicro, reboot

Dears,

I trying to reboot supermicro server first time, and it takes long time more than 30 min and not finish yet.

ram was 16G 2400T and change it to  32G 2133T

is there any advice?

Comment: Use the time to get coffee. It's normal for hardware server to take a long time to boot, the more RAM you put into it the longer it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about your server? CPU, motherboard model and BIOS version, memory partnumber and quantity.